# Google assistant helping create a diary and opening and writing at basic google apps: docs and calendar, for healthcare use tracking emotions and brea

Tags: actions-on-google

I want the following workflow using my voice at my android cell phone

1. keep a diary adding notes along the day just with my voice and few commands.
   Ex 9.00 am: (fictitious example: ok google open document diary at google docs.....ok google edit voice typing....I feel right now blablabla...og google close google doc
2. same for google calendar. Ok google open event named x today and google doc attachment there

My research on the matter:
I cant open a new google doc and start voice typing a document
I also cant open a google doc by its name either
I cant add reminders to google calendar to be speal aloud at certain time (i.e reading a google doc or description of the event)

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Welcome! StackOverflow works best when you have a specific problem that you have attempted, but are having problems with. Illustrating this with what you have tried (by showing code, screen shots of Intents, sample conversations, etc) and what isn't working (by showing error messages or incorrect responses) will help us help you find a solution. See "[ask] A Good Question"?